# Where and how to enable CORS on a Spring-Boot based WAR running on Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am running `tomcat 9` on my `VM` and deploying `Spring-Boot` based `WAR` files built using `gradle` on it.

I keep getting `CORS` errors for the `APIs` running there.

I tried enabling the `@CrossOrigin` on `Spring-boot` but the error didn't seem to go away so I changed the `web.xml` file on my `tomcat` but still the `CORS` error keeps me from accessing my `APIs`.

What am I doing wrong and Where else should I enable the `CORS` setting and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable cors support in spring boot application by adding `@CrossOrigin` annotation on controller method as follows,

```
@CrossOrigin(
    allowCredentials = "true",
    origins = "*", 
    allowedHeaders = "*", 
    methods = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.DELETE,RequestMethod.PUT}
)
```

Comment: @Nithin whats the error you get ? did you add it to every controller ?

Comment: The error i got war `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://a.example.com/fileupload/uploadfile. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`. Yep, there is only one controller I am using and I added it to that itself.

Comment: Can we start a chat? I'll share the file.

Comment: @Nithin ok, i'll check it

Comment: Hey,Thanks so much. Here's the chat room - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180413/room-for-nithin-and-benjamin-c